# Approximating time spent per user based on activity log

Tags: r, cumsum

I want to approximate how much time is spent in a program per user. My data is a log of all activity in the program. I have calculated the time difference between each log entry.

I am assuming that if you have no activity for >60 seconds, you are no longer using the program. Hence I want to summarize the length of each 'session'. In other words, I want to accumulate the time difference between each log, until the time difference is higher than 60, then I want to save the final tally and start over. Ideally, if there is just one entry (such as #21 and #23) before the tally is reset, I am assuming they used the program for 5 seconds.

If you have more clever ways to approximate time spent in the program, I would be very happy to hear your suggestions!

**Intended outcome**

```
User <- c("Bruger-138-450-251", "Bruger-138-450-251", "Bruger-138-450-251", "Bruger-138-450-251", "Bruger-338-978-988", "Bruger-338-978-988", "Bruger-338-978-988", "Bruger-338-978-988")
Time_spent <- c("322.55", "145.447", "88.88700008", "5", "5", "6.523000002", "92.62900019", "53.3499999")
        
intended_output <- data.frame(User, Time_spent)
```

**Data snippet:**

```
DF1 <- structure(
  list(
    User = c(
      "Bruger-138-450-251",
      "Bruger-138-450-251",
      "Bruger-138-450-251",
      "Bruger-138-450-251",
      "Bruger-138-450-251",
      "Bruger-138-450-251",
      "Bruger-138-450-251",
      "Bruger-138-450-251",
      "Bruger-138-450-251",
      "Bruger-138-450-251",
      "Bruger-138-450-251",
      "Bruger-138-450-251",
      "Bruger-138-450-251",
      "Bruger-138-450-251",
      "Bruger-138-450-251",
      "Bruger-138-450-251",
      "Bruger-138-450-251",
      "Bruger-138-450-251",
      "Bruger-138-450-251",
      "Bruger-138-450-251",
      "Bruger-138-450-251",
      "Bruger-338-978-988",
      "Bruger-338-978-988",
      "Bruger-338-978-988",
      "Bruger-338-978-988",
      "Bruger-338-978-988",
      "Bruger-338-978-988",
      "Bruger-338-978-988",
      "Bruger-338-978-988",
      "Bruger-338-978-988",
      "Bruger-338-978-988",
      "Bruger-338-978-988",
      "Bruger-338-978-988",
      "Bruger-338-978-988",
      "Bruger-338-978-988",
      "Bruger-338-978-988",
      "Bruger-338-978-988"
    ),
    Activity = c(
      3,
      2,
      2,
      6,
      6,
      2,
      2,
      6,
      3,
      6,
      3,
      3,
      2,
      5,
      6,
      4,
      2,
      1,
      5,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      3,
      5,
      3,
      5,
      2,
      2,
      4,
      6,
      1,
      3,
      3,
      5,
      5,
      2
    ),
    Time = structure(
      c(
        1643268505.478,
        1643268563.552,
        1643268620.463,
        1643268634.955,
        1643268679.546,
        1643268856.269,
        1643268881.907,
        1643268886.102,
        1643269006.059,
        1643269032.07,
        1643269061.255,
        1643269073.864,
        1643269096.987,
        1643269110.895,
        1643269139.23,
        1643269151.506,
        1643269749.455,
        1643269779.843,
        1643269838.342,
        1643269992.661,
        1643270125.465,
        1643268540.04,
        1643268582.205,
        1643268693.839,
        1643268700.362,
        1643269168.237,
        1643269169.208,
        1643269171.457,
        1643269202.264,
        1643269204.619,
        1643269206.852,
        1643269210.238,
        1643269249.979,
        1643269260.866,
        1643269544.183,
        1643269597.374,
        1643269597.533
      ),
      tzone = "UTC",
      class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")
    ),
    Difference = structure(
      c(
        NA,
        58.0739998817444,
        56.9110000133514,
        14.4919998645782,
        44.5910000801086,
        176.723000049591,
        25.6380000114441,
        4.1949999332428,
        119.957000017166,
        26.0110001564026,
        29.1849999427795,
        12.6089997291565,
        23.1230001449585,
        13.9079999923706,
        28.335000038147,
        12.2760000228882,
        597.948999881744,
        30.3880000114441,
        58.4990000724792,
        154.319000005722,
        132.804000139236,
        NA,
        42.164999961853,
        111.634000062943,
        6.52300000190735,
        467.875,
        0.970999956130981,
        2.24900007247925,
        30.8069999217987,
        2.35500001907349,
        2.23300004005432,
        3.38599991798401,
        39.7410001754761,
        10.8870000839233,
        283.316999912262,
        53.1909999847412,
        0.158999919891357
      ),
      units = "secs",
      class = "difftime"
    )
  ),
  class = c("grouped_df",
            "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
  row.names = c(NA,-37L),
  groups = structure(
    list(
      User = c("Bruger-138-450-251", "Bruger-338-978-988"),
      .rows = structure(
        list(1:21, 22:37),
        ptype = integer(0),
        class = c("vctrs_list_of",
                  "vctrs_vctr", "list")
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-2L),
    class = c("tbl_df",
              "tbl", "data.frame"),
    .drop = TRUE
  )
)
```

I have looked at the following posts with no success:

- [Cumulative sum until maximum reached, then repeat from zero in the next row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466880/cumulative-sum-until-maximum-reached-then-repeat-from-zero-in-the-next-row)
- [R: Sum until 0 is reached and then restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53651782/r-sum-until-0-is-reached-and-then-restart)
- [Sum until a given value is reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32124549/sum-until-a-given-value-is-reached)