# Dplyr conditional windowing

Tags: r, dplyr

Trying to convert the following R data.frame:

```
    structure(list( Time=c("09:30:01"  ,"09:30:29"  ,"09:35:56",  "09:37:17"  ,"09:37:21"  ,"09:37:28"  ,"09:37:35"  ,"09:37:51"  ,"09:42:11"  ,"10:00:31"),
            Price=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
            Volume=c(100,200,300,100,200,300,100,200,600,100)),
      .Names = c("Time", "Price", "Volume"),
      row.names = c(NA,10L),
      class = "data.frame")

           Time Price Volume
    1  09:30:01     1    100
    2  09:30:29     2    200
    3  09:35:56     3    300
    4  09:37:17     4    100
    5  09:37:21     5    200
    6  09:37:28     6    300
    7  09:37:35     7    100
    8  09:37:51     8    200
    9  09:42:11     9    600
    10 10:00:31    10    100
```

into this

```
       Time Price  Volume Bin
1  09:30:01     1     100   1
2  09:30:29     2     200   1
3  09:35:56     3     200   1
4  09:35:56     3     100   2
5  09:37:17     4     100   2
6  09:37:21     5     200   2
7  09:37:28     6     100   2
8  09:37:28     6     200   3
9  09:37:35     7     100   3
10 09:37:51     8     200   3
11 09:42:11     9     500   4
12 09:42:11     9     100   5
13 10:00:31    10     100   5
```

Essentially, it is calculating cumulative sums on volume and binning eachtime 500 is breached. So, bin 1 is 100+200+200 with the volume at 09:35:56 split into 200/100 and a new row inserted and the bin counter incremented.

This is relatively straightforward with base R but I was wondering is there a more elegant and hopefully faster way with dplyr.

Cheers

Update:

Thank you @Frank and @AntoniosK.

To address your question the range of volume values is all positive integers values from 1 to 10k.

I microbenchmarked both approaches and dplyr was slightly faster but not much in it, on a dataset similar to above with ~200k rows.

Really appreciate the swift responses and assistance

Comment: Maybe you should show the "relatively straightforward" way you've tried. I'm guessing there is not an elegant dplyr approach, but there may be room for improvement in your base R tack.

Comment: Are you always going to have values like 100,200, etc? Or this is a simplified case?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466880/cumulative-sum-until-maximum-reached-then-repeat-from-zero-in-the-next-row

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is the best or fastest way, but seems fast for those `Volume` values. The philosophy is simple. Based on the `Volume` value you have create that many rows of `Time` and `Price` with `Volume = 1`. Then let `cumsum` add the numbers and flag every time you have a new 500 batch. Use those flags to create your `Bin` values.

```
structure(list( Time=c("09:30:01"  ,"09:30:29"  ,"09:35:56",  "09:37:17"  ,"09:37:21"  ,"09:37:28"  ,"09:37:35"  ,"09:37:51"  ,"09:42:11"  ,"10:00:31"),
                Price=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                Volume=c(100,200,300,100,200,300,100,200,600,100)),
          .Names = c("Time", "Price", "Volume"),
          row.names = c(NA,10L),
          class = "data.frame") -> dt

library(dplyr)

dt %>%
  group_by(Time, Price) %>%                     ## for each Time and Price
  do(data.frame(Volume = rep(1,.$Volume))) %>%  ## create as many rows, with Volume = 1, as the value of Volume
  ungroup() %>%                                 ## forget about the grouping
  mutate(CumSum = cumsum(Volume),               ## cumulative sums 
         flag_500 = ifelse(CumSum %in% seq(501,sum(dt$Volume),by=500),1,0),  ## flag 500 batches (at 501, 1001, etc.)
         Bin = cumsum(flag_500)+1) %>%          ## create Bin values 
  group_by(Bin, Time, Price) %>%                ## for each Bin, Time and Price
  summarise(Volume = sum(Volume)) %>%           ## get new Volume values
  select(Time, Price, Volume, Bin) %>%          ## use only if you want to re-arrange column order
  ungroup()                                     ## use if you want to forget the grouping

#        Time Price Volume   Bin
#       (chr) (dbl)  (dbl) (dbl)
# 1  09:30:01     1    100     1
# 2  09:30:29     2    200     1
# 3  09:35:56     3    200     1
# 4  09:35:56     3    100     2
# 5  09:37:17     4    100     2
# 6  09:37:21     5    200     2
# 7  09:37:28     6    100     2
# 8  09:37:28     6    200     3
# 9  09:37:35     7    100     3
# 10 09:37:51     8    200     3
# 11 09:42:11     9    500     4
# 12 09:42:11     9    100     5
# 13 10:00:31    10    100     5
```

Answer (score 3):

This is hardly "straightforward."

With data.table, it's still many lines of code:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)
DF[, c("cV","cVL") := shift(cumsum(Volume), 0:1, type="lag", fill=0) ]
DF[, end   := ( cV %/% 500 ) - ( cV %% 500 == 0 ) ]
DF[, start := shift(end, type = "lag", fill = -1) + ( cVL %% 500 == 0 ) ]

badcols = c("Volume","cV","cVL","start","end")
DF[,{
  V = 
    if (start==end) Volume
    else c((start+1)*500-cVL, rep(500, max(end-start-2,0)), cV - end*500) 

  c(.SD[, !badcols, with=FALSE], list(Volume = V, Bin = 1+start:end))
}, by=.(r=seq(nrow(DF)))][,!"r",with=FALSE]
```

which gives

```
        Time Price Volume Bin
 1: 09:30:01     1    100   1
 2: 09:30:29     2    200   1
 3: 09:35:56     3    200   1
 4: 09:35:56     3    100   2
 5: 09:37:17     4    100   2
 6: 09:37:21     5    200   2
 7: 09:37:28     6    100   2
 8: 09:37:28     6    200   3
 9: 09:37:35     7    100   3
10: 09:37:51     8    200   3
11: 09:42:11     9    500   4
12: 09:42:11     9    100   5
13: 10:00:31    10    100   5
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way using `data.table` and it's *rolling joins* feature:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.6+
setDT(df)[, csum := cumsum(Volume)]
ans = rbind(df, df[.(csum=500 * seq_len(max(csum)%/% 500L)), roll=-Inf, on="csum"])
setorder(ans, Price, csum)
ans = ans[, `:=`(Volume = c(csum[1L], diff(csum)), 
                 id     = (csum-1L) %/% 500L + 1L, 
                 csum   = NULL)][Volume > 0L]
```

The first step adds a new column with the cumulative sum of `Volume`.

The second step is perhaps the most important. Let's look at the second part. For each multiple of `500` until `max(csum)`, it joins to the first value >= a multiple of 500 on `df$csum`. It's a *rolling NOCB join* (next observation carried backward). With that we'd get:

```
#        Time Price Volume csum
# 1: 09:35:56     3    300  500
# 2: 09:37:28     6    300 1000
# 3: 09:37:51     8    200 1500
# 4: 09:42:11     9    600 2000
```

These are the break points that needs to be added to your original data.table. That's what we do with `rbind()`.

Then, all we do is to order by `Price, csum`, generate back `Volume` column. From there, generating `id` column can be done using `csum` column as shown.